# ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller or View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Lets say I render a partial view within some view (using @Html.RenderPartial("")).
Does the controller look for this partial or is it the ViewEngine? Assume the partial view doesn't exist in the controller's Home area. This is so confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the `Html.RenderAction` helper, for `Html.RenderPartial` it is the view engine which will look for the corresponding partial view and include it at the specified location in the main View. There's no controller involved in this process. And if the partial view doesn't exist in the controller's home area you could always specify the full path to it:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Foo/Bar")
```

Comment: I'm not sure, so would the View Engine look in the Shared folder for this partial view and throw an exception if it doesnt exist? or does the controller search each areas Home folder for the view?

Comment: I am not quite sure about it, but it should be pretty straightforward for you to verify. I think it follows the same conventions as the standard view rules: first it looks at the same folder in which the main view is located and then in the Shared.

Comment: I have verified it, it seems to work in both cases if the view is in the Shared folder or in the controller's area folder. What I can't seem to understand is that is the controller that is "controlling" all this or is it the view engine.

Comment: It is the view engine. No controller is involved in this process. The controller's purpose is to render a view (a.k.a. `return View()`). From that moment on, it is the `V` letter of MVC that takes all the responsibility.

Comment: But in rendering the view would the controller not need to find it ?

Comment: No, it is the view engine that locates the view using the built-in conventions. For example you could write a custom view engine which will load the views from a database instead of the file system. The only information that is passed along from the controller to the view engine is the view name and a view model.

Comment: @user7007558 Note that the view engine has access to the route data, which means it knows the name of the controller and action for the current request. This information is used to determine in which directory to go to find the view.

Comment: so in this case the view engine will look for the partial view in the Shared folder and if it doesn't exist will throw an exception?

Comment: Before looking into the Shared folder it will look into the folder containing the main view. If not found in those 2 locations it will throw an exception. By the way, when such exception is thrown the error text is pretty self-explanatory as it is telling you all the locations it searched and in which order.

Comment: ok cool, so the controller would never look in any folder shared or area folder ?